# How to publish a Microsoft Forms(Office 365 form) with Azure DevOps Pipeline on different environments?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, office365, microsoft-forms

I have a solution that consists of Azure Logic Apps, functions app, Sharepoint, and Office 365 forms.  I want to keep all the resources in the git and deploy automated. Currently, I can deploy Azure Logic Apps, and functions apps via ARM templates.
I want to integrate Microsoft Forms(Office 365 forms) with Azure DevOps.
Is it possible to integrate Microsoft Forms(Office 365 forms) inside a task for AzureDevops?

In the end, we want to create a Release/Deploy for several different environments.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to integrate Office 365 Forms with a simple task like Azure Logic Apps.

You need to publish Office 365 Forms just as you publish Office Add-in. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio) for details.